# Ember data parent / child models and json

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I want to document once and for all for myself (and keep a permanent record!) of the relationship between parents and children and the ideal json structure, along with basic examples of routes and controllers.

As I (hopefully) get answers and comments I will update the question to reflect best practice.

So, I have my ember models :

```
App.Customer  = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string' ),
    orders: DS.hasMany("order")
});

App.Order  = DS.Model.extend({
    carrier: DS.attr('string' ),
    customer: DS.belongsTo("customer")
    orderlines: DS.hasMany("orderline")

});

App.Orderline  = DS.Model.extend({
    order: DS.belongsTo("order"),
    item: DS.belongsTo("item"),
    price: DS.attr('number'),
    qty: DS.attr('number'),
});

App.Item  = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    orderlines: DS.hasMany("orderline")
});
```

**Question 1:** are these model definitions correct ?

There are several approaches that I could take to viewing this data:

- Customer Tab | Orders Tab | Order lines tab
- Customer page -> Orders Page -> Order lines page
- Treeview
- Can anyone suggest any other JS widgets that could display this hierarchical data ?

**Question 2:**

what are the router / controllers that are required for each of these ?

I have option 2) working as far as displaying the customer, but when I click on the orders link for the customer I am getting all orders. It could be that my json is wrong .. or more likely I don't know how to display all the orders of the selected customer. Or both :(

I currently have :

```
{"customers":[
  {"name":"foobar inc","id":"0x181","orders":["0x386","0x3a4"]},
  {"name":"barfoo ltd","id":"0x182","orders":["0x3de","0x3fd"]} ],   
 "orders":[
   {"carrier":"Standard Mail","id":"0x386","customer_id":"0x181"},
   {"carrier":"FlyByNight Courier","id":"0x3a4","customer_id":"0x181"},
   {"carrier":"Standard Mail","id":"0x3de","customer_id":"0x182"},
   {"carrier":"FlyByNight Courier","id":"0x3fd","customer_id":"0x182"} ]}
```

**Question 3:** is this correct ? (I can make the json come out in any format, so it's probably best to create the json structure that best suits ember-data).

**Question 4:** should I be including related data at this point (so all customers, all orders, all orderlines)? Or would it be better not to include the child data, but get these on demand from the server ?

I'll leave it for now - hopefully I can start to make sense of the nested data soon ! thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1** Those model definitions look good to me.

**Question 2** You may want to end up with a mixture of your options #1 and #2.  Tabs to let you see the entire list of each model, but with the ability to drill down hierarchically, on the `/customers` page, for instance.  The exact routes that you need depend on the exact URLs that you want to have available in your app which will correspond to the screens/views that you want to show.

Let's say that you wanted these URLs/screens

`/customers` - The list of all customers

`/customers/1` - The details about customer #1

`/customers/1/orders` - All orders for customer #1

`/customers/1/orders/1` - The details for order #1 (including `OrderLine`s)

Then your routes would be:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('customers');
    this.resource('customer', { path: '/customers/:customer_id' }, function(){
        this.resource('orders');
        this.resource('order', { path: '/orders/:order_id'});
    });
});
```

**Question 3** Yes, that JSON looks correct.

**Question 4** That depends on the needs of your app.  Probably you don't want to include the entire tree of data in a single request (Customers -> Orders -> OrderLines -> Items).  You probably want to progressively load things as the user goes down a tree.

For instance you'd want to load just list list of customers at first, and then when the user clicks on a customer, you'd want to fire a request to get all of the orders for that customer.  And so on, down the tree.

Here's a JSBin showing the general idea : http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1074/edit

Note that the `hasMany` relationships are defined with `{async:true}`.  This allows them to be looked up on demand, instead of loaded with the parent model.

If you switched to the `RESTAdapter`, when it tries to load the list of orders for a customer it would make a request like :

`/orders?ids[]=0x3de&ids[]=0x3fd`

[UPDATE] : In response to the comments.

So, for the url structure that you requested : > >List of customers > -> customer details > -> list of orders > -> order details > -> list of order lines > -> order line details

You are very close with your JSBin.  The thing that's tripping you up is the way that nesting of templates works.

The `'order'` template, if it exists, is rendered for any and all routes that match `/orders/xxx` or `/orders/xxx/*`.  If there are other parts of the route like `/orderlines` those templates get rendered into the `'order'` template.  But, since your `'order'` template doesn't have an `{{outlet}}` there is nothing for the `'orderlines'` template to render into.

Here's a slightly modified JSBin : http://jsbin.com/iKIsisO/3/edit

The only change there is the addition of the `{{outlet}}` to the bottom of the `'order'` template.

Now, rendering `orderlines` below, or otherwise inside of the main order detail may not be what you want.  Most likely you want the orderlines to replace the other order info.  In this case you can rename the `'order'` template to be `'order/index'`.  (You can also remove the `OrderRoute` and the `needs` from the `OrderController`).

Another JSBin, with the template renamed : http://jsbin.com/iDiMOCO/1/edit

#### So, what's happening here?

Using the `Order` model as an example, when you visit the `/orders` route, and any other routes that apply to the collection (`/orders/new`, `/orders/some_custom_batch_thing`), the main `'orders'` template is rendered if it exists, then the sub path templates are rendered into `'orders'`.  If the `'orders'` template does not exist, then the sub-path templates render into the `{{outlet}}` that is immediately up the chain. The `/orders` route is kind of a special case in that the sub-template for it is implicitly assumed to be `orders/index`.  Similarly, with `/orders/xxx` and any other routes that apply to a single `Order`, the `'order'` template is rendered first (if it exists), then the sub-path templates are rendered, either into `'order'`, or into the most immediate parent `{{outlet}}`.  Also with `/orders/xxx` the `'order/index'` template is the implicit sub-path template.

- `/orders`     :: `'orders'` -> `'orders/index'`
- `/orders/new` :: `'orders'` -> `'orders/new'`
- `/order/xxx` :: `'order'` -> `'order/index'`
- `/orders/xxx/edit` :: `'order'` -> `'order/edit'`

So, the `'orders'` and `'order'` templates are really kind of like per-model-layout templates that can be used to decorate the sub-paths in a consistent way.

Final JSBin with template names rendered in the template and a few extra templates added to act as "model layouts": http://jsbin.com/iKIsisO/2/edit

I hope that all makes sense.

Comment: Jeremy, as usual you are always one of the first to help ;) Thanks. Please bear with me, as I am a JS and ember newbie (if you haven't already guessed!)

Comment: >ok, can we take a scenario where we have one page per item :
>
>List of customers
> -> customer details  
> -> list of orders  
>   -> order details  
>   -> list of order lines  
>      -> order line details  
  
I am using a REST adapter to get the json, and can change the json to match whatever is required, so I am interested to see what the appropriate json structure for this scenario is, as well as the routes and templates  
I am trying to get this working myself, but keep hitting brick walls - and thanks to guys like you my hammer and chisel is getting bigger and better!

Comment: basically , I want to show a grid of customers, where I can click a link to see the customer details (done this) , click a link to see the orders of a customer. From here I want to be able to click a link to see order details (can do this) and click a clink to see the order lines of an order. From here I want to click a link to see order line details  All of these are to be on seperate pages

Comment: ok, so I've made some modifications to your jsbin, and gotten a bit further. The only problem so far is that I can't see the orderlines page (it always shows the order page). 

http://jsbin.com/iKIsisO/1/edit

Comment: OK, I just added an [UPDATE] to my original answer.

Comment: thanks for the detailed response. I'll try and wrap my tired brain round this - I am honestly so near the point of giving up on ember because it is taking _so_ long to work around / with the "cleverness" ;)

Comment: If I may impose on you one last time - do I need nested routes / resources (wtf is the difference between them?) or can I list them at the same level, but still manage the url as customer/:id/orders/:id/orderlines/:id (or any subsection thereof) ? I really want to be able to render each segment into the application outlet (I don't want to have subsections). thanks so myuch for your time on this. It is appreciated

Comment: If you want nested urls you need nested routes.  If you want each one to go into the application outlet, just make sure that you're using the `*/index` templates/routes/controllers for all of your models instead of the raw singular/plural name of your model.  So instead of 'customers' use 'customers/index', then instead of 'customer' it's 'customer/index', and then 'orders/index' and 'order/index' and so on.